# Exception While using Proxy in Http Rest Client

Tags: java, rest, https, proxy, salesforce

Hi I am using Http Rest Client to Log in In SalesForce Oauth Authentication....
When I am without Proxy the program working fine....but using Https with Proxy setting is not working for me.....My code is.....

public class SfChatter {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException,
        HttpException, IOException, SOAPException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    System.out.println("started");

    try {

        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "proxy.company.com");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "80");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "abcde");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "********");

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
                System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
                System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
            }
        } }, new SecureRandom());

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
        Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

        // apache HttpClient version >4.2 should use
        // BasicClientConnectionManager
        ClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(
                schemeRegistry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");

        String username = "------------";
        String password = "---------------";
        String client_id = "3MVGS";
        String client_secret = "894448";

        List<BasicNameValuePair> parametersBody = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        parametersBody
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret",
                client_secret));

        postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody));
        postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (response.getEntity().getContent())));

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj = parser.parse(br.readLine());

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

        String id = (String) jsonObject.get("id");
        System.out.println("ID: " + id);

        String access_token = (String) jsonObject.get("access_token");
        System.out.println("ACCESS_TOKEN: " + access_token);

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

But while Running it I am getting this Connection Exception.....

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://login.salesforce.com refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.chatter.sf.SfChatter.main(SfChatter.java:100)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:549)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: This can even occur due to slow internet connection

Comment: @Nabin  Sometimes i do get connection timed out error which is due to slow internet connection.
i am getting **connection refused** error. Can connection refused also be due to same reason?

Comment: It might be due to serverdown..

Comment: @Nabin Don't think its server related as i have been trying this for quite few days now and Salesforce server can be down for so long. I feel its the issue with the proxy. The api only supports HTTPS calls. Can you confirm that the proxy setting that i have done above in the code for HTTP will apply to HTTPS as well? If not, how to specify proxy for HTTPS?